# Is there a way to edit my current Game Center Leaderboard once my iOS app is live?

Tags: ios, game-center, leaderboard

So I saw that I made a mistake when i set up my Leaderboard in my game. I set it as "Low to High" instead of "High to Low" and that looks awful.
Now whenever I try to do something to my current leaderboard, itunes connect gives me an error saying:

```
"We can't process your request.

Try reloading the page. If the problem persists, contact Us."
```

The status of my Leaderboard says "Live". Is it because of that? I can't do any change on that because it's Live? How am I supposed to change anything now?

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently an Apple related bug on iTunesConnect. They try to fix it asap.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66402

Comment: ohhh cool! i will give it a call, i tried a minute ago but it's closed now.. i gotta wait! THANK you soo much man, i was desperate, i was about to call either way today but i know apple is hard to handle when it comes to support, they always say "they can't". I was so worried, thanks again!